# How to have two different domains with same content except the contact info

Tags: wordpress, dns

Do you guys have an idea how to do this?

I have a website (mywebsite.nl) and another domain (mywebsite.be). I want mywebsite.be to have the same look and content as mywebsite.nl except the contact info is different.

Thanks!

Comment: This my not be a good idea because it will lead to duplicate content, something Google punishes in ranking.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using WordPress then checkout their multi site functionality.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Should be able to apply the same theme to multiple sites.

Comment: A multi site itself will not share content, it won't help here. Just theme's/plugins/logins and some settings.

Answer (score 1):

in PHP and thus in wordpress you can get the name of the server and change your contactinfo depending on it:

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']=='www.mywebsite.be') echo "belgium address";
else echo "dutch address";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only make one site, and just add 2 contact forms/contact information for each counties.
And put a redirect on one domain.

And like @pekka said, google *will* punish the content duplication.
Besides that in the source code domain names will get messed up and make your visitors cross domains unintended.

Comment: But will Google index the .be website (redirected domain) with that approach?

Comment: if you use the .nl as the main, and redirect .be to .nl then google will also be redirected and index .nl Nothing wrong with that. Google will also index the Belgium contact page.

Comment: it will index .be? is this approach possible with WordPress?

Comment: You don't get it. if you use the .be as a redirect there will be no .be pages, they will all be redirected to the .nl version. Therefore there are no .be pages to index, a redirect is not depending on wordpress of an other cms